# Python - Get/Set active hair particle keys

Tags: python, scripting, particles, hair

Is there any way to get and set selected hair keys in Blender 2.8 and later?

Getting and manipulating the coordinates is easy but that's not what I need; I'm trying to create an operator to select specific keys similarly to the select roots/tips from the Particle Edit mode.

**Things I've tried that didn't work:**

- I've poured over the API without success. It doesn't look like there's an operator nor any object or data holding their selected/unselected status.
- More creative workarounds also didn't work because hair keys don't seem to exist in the same manner vertices do. Trying to set the cursor to them sets it to the emitter's origin; converting the particle system to object resets the selected status of hair keys (now vertices) previously selected.